# How to get an Fancybox error or href of image that it trying to load but can't?

Tags: javascript, fancybox, message

Question is already been asked in title.

Here is a code:

```
(function($){
        var filter = /(.*)(\.jpg|\.png|\.gif|\.bmp)$/i;

        $('a > img').each(function(){

            var href = $(this).parent().attr('href');

            if ( filter.test(href) ){
                $(this).fancybox({
                    transitionIn:'fade',
                    transitionOut:'fade',
                    overlayShow:true,
                    overlayOpacity:0.7,
                    overlayColor:'#e8f1fa'
                });
            }
        });
    })($);
```

So, as you can see, the aim in that to set up a fancybox on a sequence "a > img", where "A" tag have link on an image.

Here is a problem place: http://factorial.wispo.ru/novosti/skoro-budet-sajt.html

Comment: Lol! The answer is easy - it needs to specify the fancybox on the "A" tag. So, there is a fix: $(this).parent().fancybox(... Thanks for focus and HAD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is easy - it needs to specify the fancybox on the "A" tag. So, there is a fix: $(this).parent().fancybox(... Thanks for focus and HAD